# Laravel belongsTo Relationship

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

Ok, I am a little confused with the belongsTo relationship for Models.

I have a Feeds model that extends Eloguent.

I have created a relationship function called User.

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo('User'); // and I also tried return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}
```

On the view I am trying to do :

```
@foreach($feeds as $feed)
{{$feed->user()->first_name}} {{$feed->user()->last_name}}
@endforeach
```

but I am getting this error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$last_name

When I do $feed->user->first_name it works fine, but I thought user()->first_name was more efficient. What am I doing wrong?

This are the fields and data types of the database:

feeds

```
feed_id INT
user_id INT
feed Text
created_at TIMESTAMP
updated_at TIMSTAMP
school_id INT
```

users

```
user_id INT
username VARCHAR
password VARCHAR
first_name VARCHAR
last_name VARCHAR
created_at TIMESTAMP
updated_at TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the dynamic property

```
$feed->user->first_name;
```

When you use the dynamic property it is the same as doing the below except Laravel does it for you using the magic `__call()` method.

```
$feed->user()->first()->first_name;
```

using just the function $feed->user() allows you to get the relationship which allows you to add extra constraints and `with` relations before fetching the entity on the other end.

Comment: So $feed->$user->first_name is the same as the examples of $feed->user()->first_name but if I want to call another relationship or additional information (say from a pivot table), then I can user the function to make that connection?

Comment: Does $feed->$user->first_name create the N+1 issue?

Comment: $feed->user->someProperty does not cause N+1 issue itself. N+1 issue is calling such code within a loop eg. foreach ($feeds as $feed). For a single $feed this is not a problem, but for a collection you should use eager loading.

Comment: I had a feeling. So, in the posted question which is in a loop, how can I eager load the user's information so it doesn't?

Comment: When you fetch your feeds use with, e.g. `Feeds::with('user')->...` which will grab all the user information in the same query.

Comment: I tried $feeds = Feed::with('User')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(6); 
but got this error:
 Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$first_name (View: /var/www/getumoving.org/app/views/main/main.blade.php) 
with a relationship of in the Feed model:
 public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id','user_id');
    }
My view looks like:
{{$feed->user()->first_name}} {{$feed->user()->last_name}}

Comment: You still need to use `$feed->user->first_name` when you use `with(...)` and the dynamic property it will pull the user from the returned results (that it fetched at the same time) instead of asking the database.

Comment: Oh ok. So despite being the same code, 'with' will negate the n+1 problem?

Comment: Correct, With essentially preloads the data for you.