# Dealing with Eloquent relationships in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables created using `Schema`s:

```
  Schema::create('typen', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
  });

 Schema::create('auktionen', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('typ')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('typ')->references('id')->on('typen');
  });
```

The table `typen` is only created once at contains fixed values:

```
Typen
id| name
1 | Typ 1
2 | Typ 2
...
```

Those values are constant, no more will be added during the application lifetime. So every `Auktion` I create should be associated with one `Typ`.
I created the model for `Auktion` and thought of it as a one-to-one relationship (is this correct?).

I would like to create an Auktion with a given Typ using Eloquent queries like this:

```
  $thetyp = App\Typ::where("id", "=", 1)->first();
  $auktion->typ()->associate($thetyp);
```

and fetch the `name` of the `Typ` of my `Auktion`:

```
$auktion->typ->name;
```

Currently my model looks like this for `Auktion`:

```
  public function typ()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Typ', 'typ');
  }
```

which is not working. I already tried setting different relationships but I just end in different error codes ranging from undefined methods `(associate()` to an error where an SQL statement failed trying to update my `typen` table (when using `save()` - which I really do not want to).

Can someone clarify this problem for me and explain which relationship I have to use?

**EDIT1**: As mentioned in a comment I already tried using `belongsTo` in `Auktion` model

```
  public function typ()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Typ', 'typ');
  }
```

which results in `Undefined property: App\Auktion::$typ` when calling

```
 $thetyp = App\Typ::where("id", "=", 1)->first();
 $auktion->typ()->save($thetyp);
```

and when calling `$auktion->typ->name;` in

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

**EDIT2**:

I just figured that

```
echo $auktion->typ()->first()->name;
```

is indeed working. [But referring to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208469/laravel-belongsto-relationship) this should be the same as

```
echo $auktion->typ->name;
```

What exactly am i doing wrong?

**EDIT3**:

I tried using suggested code:

```
  $thetyp = App\Typ::find($typ);
  $auktion->typ->save($thetyp);
```

After I navigated to the view ehere I run the code I got this:

[image]

I got this the second time today, somwhow out of nowhere

Comment: Please see my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code enhancement:

```
 $thetyp = App\Typ::where("id", "=", 1)->first();
 $auktion->typ()->save($thetyp);
```

To:

```
//Will return null if Model is not found
$thetyp = App\Typ::find(1);
//You actually have to retrieve the relationship, because calling typ()
//will only retrieve the Relationship query
$auktion->typ()->get()->save($thetyp);
```

The problem is that the relationship is defined backwards. You need to make Auction `belongTo` Type, and change Type to `hasMany` Auctions. The statement would read:

"A Type has many Auctions. An Auction has one Type".

Here are the classes (in English, sorry, my German is bad :( so I just did it in English) with the migrations:

-Auction class:

```
class Auction extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'auction';

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Type');
    }
}
```

-Auction migration:

```
Schema::create('auction', function(Blueprint $table){

$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('type_id')->references('id')->on('type')->nullable();
$table->string('title')->nullable();
$table->string('description')->nullable();

$table->timestamps();

});
```

-Type class:

```
class Type extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'type';

    public function auction()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Auction');
    }
}
```

-Type migration:

```
 Schema::create('type', function(Blueprint $table){

      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('name');

      $table->timestamps();
 });
```

First, you can create a `Type` object (or insert it with a query) so we can have a `Type` row that we can relate to an `Auction` object/entry, and do the following:

```
//Example of Type obj creation

$type = new Type();
$type->name = 'Type #1';
//Don't forget to save
$type->save();

//OR find/retrieve a Type obj

//Where $id is the id of the Type obj, else the obj will be null
$type = Type::find($id);

$auction = new Auction();

$auction->title = 'Title #1';
$auction->description = 'Test description';

$auction->type_id = $type->id;

//Don't forget to save
$auction->save();
```

Now later in your code, whenever you are using an `Auction` object and you want to retrieve the associated type (if any), you can use:

`$type = $auction->type()->get();`

Which will return the instance of `Type`, and you will be able to retrieve the property name like so:

`$type->name`

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any more questions!

Answer (score 1):

Your second edit makes a lot of sense.  Your method name is `typ` but that's also the name of the column.  So when you use `$auktion->typ()` it's actually loading the relationship.  When you use `$auktion->typ` it's grabbing the value of that column.

You need to either continue working this way using the parenthesis to load the relation and no parenthesis to grab the value of the column, or you can change the name of the column to something better such as `typ_id` which is ultimately what Laravel expects it to be and should save you from more similar headaches down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your Auktion model

```
$thetyp = App\Typ::find(1);
$auktion->typ->save($thetyp);
```

Now fetch

```
$auktion->typ->name
```

Comment: remove parenthesis. try  $auktion->typ->save($thetyp);

Comment: `Undefined property: App\Auktion::$typ`

Comment: What is your goal overall? Get a relationship established between 2 objects? It looks like you are trying to bring the type of an auction with its' defined method. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah exactly, at the moment I am just assigning the `id` of `Typ` when I create an `Auktion`. Also when I am accessing `$auktion->typ` I will only retreive the `id`, but I want to be able to acces the whole `Model` including `name` as well

Comment: Is your $auktion->typ giving you null ??

Comment: No it is giving me the id of Typ

Comment: I have the answer, I am elaborating on it. Will post it soon.

Comment: I tried. see my update :'( Had this already and only way to fix it was kill the VM